# How do I get mouse click to position cursor to work in konsole with bash?

Tags: bash, mouse, konsole

I would like to be able to click the mouse button in konsole to position the cursor in bash. How do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In konsole 22.08 onwards, there is the ability to click the left mouse button to position the cursor in bash (a feature not present in Gnome's or Cinnamon's terminals). I had some trouble getting it to work so thought I'd share my solution.

You have to do two things get it working. One is change a setting in konsole settings and the second is to add some lines to `.bashrc`. It sounds easy, but the first is hindered by a bug and the second just didn't work for me.

The konsole setting can be found in Settings -> Configure Konsole. A new window opens and you go to Profiles in there. For me, the built in profile is read only so I had to make a new profile, but I could not save the new profile. Every time I exited, the profile disappeared. I found a workaround to the bug [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/openSUSE/comments/x99rnq/comment/inpni5o/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3): basically you never click "Apply" when creating the profile only "Ok", close settings window and konsole, then reopen.

In the profile, under General, there is a tab "Semantic Integration". "Mouse click in input line" needs to be selected.

In the konsole, you are supposed to press Ctrl+Alt+I then search for "semantic integration" and put what appears there in your `.bashrc` to make it permanent. However, that didn't work for me even though those same lines executed manually in bash in konsole worked fine temporarily. I had to add these lines at the end of my `.bashrc` instead:

```
if [[ ! $PS1 =~ 133 ]] ; then
    source ~/.local/share/DomTerm/bash-preexec.sh
    source ~/.local/share/DomTerm/shell-integration.bash
fi
```

`bash-preexec.sh` and `shell-integration.bash` are copied from another terminal called DomTerm (that also offers click to position cursor) into `~/.local/share/DomTerm`. Those files can be found [here](https://github.com/PerBothner/DomTerm/tree/master/tools).

I have found this setup works when using bash-it themes.